# Dataframe reads images from folders in big difference memory size

Tags: python, pandas, opencv

I have multiple folders of images that I read them into dataframe, each folder in a dataframe row with it is associated data . The whole folders size is 350 MB , but when I read it into dataframe the total size becomes 24GB , any idea why this is happening ?

```
   videos = pd.DataFrame()
   filepath= 'C:/Users/sarmad/Documents/data/labels_metadata.csv''
   metadf = pd.read_csv(filepath)
   metadf.index = metadf.Instance_name

   for folder in folders:
     pth_upd = pth + folder + '/'
     metacsv= 
      ' pd.read_csv('C:/Users/sarmad/Documents/dev/'+format(folder)+'.csv')



x=format(folder)
meta = metadf.loc[format(folder)]
meta = pd.DataFrame([meta.values], index=[folder], columns=metadf.columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[folder])
df = df.join(meta) 

allfiles = os.listdir(pth_upd)
files = []
columns = ['data']
for file in allfiles:
    files.append(file) if ('.jpg' in file) else None
    samples = np.empty((1,227,227))

for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(pth_upd,file),0)
    img = img.reshape(1,227,227)
    img=img.astype(np.float32)
    samples = np.append(samples, img, axis=0)


result = pd.DataFrame(([[samples]]), index=[folder], columns=['videos'])


print(samples.shape)

videos=videos.append(result)
```

videos.info(memory_usage='deep')

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 Index: 2 entries, dev_001 to dev_060
 Data columns (total  1 columns):
 videos    60 non-null object
 dtypes: object(1)
 memory usage: 24GB
```

Comment: images saved as jpg (compressed) on disk are smaller than images loaded in memory (uncompressed)

Comment: How can I fix this ? the images was .bmp with size on disk (3 GB) I converted them into jpg now size is 350 MB but when I read in into df it is 24 GB

Answer (score 1):

Would it be helpful if you use `np.int8` instead of `np.float32` when you converting the image? Since the RGB value is of range (0, 255) which can be represented as an 8-bit integer.

However, it only, theoretically, reduces the size of memory by a factor of 4, so it still occupies 6GB of memory.

Comment: Thanks , I tried it It is the same result not changed the size.